# Given a latitude ,longitude and radius, find all contacts in that region. But the table contains only latitud nad longitude columns

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

The solution could finding the min and max lat and longitudes.
and then using the between condition in select query to fetch results.
But how do i get the max and min latitudes and longitudes in pl/sql.

Comment: Postgres may have a geospatial library to make this easier, but to do this by brute force you may use the Haversine formula.

Comment: i dont have the two latitudes and longitude. I just have starting latitude and longitude. and radius is given. For example: latitude and longitude of London is given and a radius of 100 miles. I am supposed to find all contacts in and around london with 100 mile radius.

Comment: What are the latitude longitude points in your table?  What does SQL have to do with this?

Comment: Oracle has a complete geospatial library, SDO_GEOMETRY in the MDSYS schema (See Spatial User's Guide and Reference for your version). It's perhaps not quite as easy to use as Postgres, but it is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have a plsql-problem, you need a formular. Here some plsql-code which calcutales the pythagorean theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem):

```
declare
    v_yourX NUMBER := 0;
    v_yourY NUMBER := 0;

    v_anotherX NUMBER := 0;
    v_anotherY NUMBER := 1;

    v_diffX NUMBER;
    v_diffY NUMBER;

    v_distance NUMBER;
begin
    v_diffX := v_yourX - v_anotherX;
    v_diffY := v_yourY - v_anotherY;

    v_distance := sqrt(v_diffX*v_diffX + v_diffY*v_diffY);

    dbms_output.put_line('Distance: ' || v_distance); 
end;
```

You want to select something out of the data-base. Here an example how to do it with a single query:

```
SELECT t.*, sqrt(t.posX*t.posX + t.posY+posY) as distance FROM
(
    select (0 - :yourX) posX, (0 - :yourY) posY from dual UNION ALL -- fake-table
    select (1 - :yourX) posX, (2 - :yourY) posY from dual UNION ALL
    select (2 - :yourX) posX, (10 - :yourY) posY from dual
) t
WHERE sqrt(t.posX*t.posX + t.posY+posY) < :maxDistance
```